# Python 3.5.2 and PyGame 1.9.2, pygame.event.get() not recognizing Keystokes

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So I have looked around the site and others quite a bit trying to figure out why my arrow keys do not seem to be recognized when trying to move my figure in pygame. I have tried several fixes but no luck. I see my cursor move in the terminal when I press the arrow keys but it does nothing in my game window(even if I make sure that the game window is the active one). When I print the event statements it appears only the mouse is being recognized.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')


def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x, y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

while not crashed: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x, y)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I see the window with my "racecar" just fine, I just can't get the thing to move.
***EDIT*** 
The answer regarding the "events" typo did not fix the problem (I made the typo when trying one of 20 or so different variations I apologize for the mistake). Regardless the edited code still does not allow me to move the car. The cursor moves in the console even when the game display is the active window.

Comment: I saw similar code with `racecar` and `apple` yesterday or few days ago in other question :)

Comment: Either I am not finding what you are referring to or the code is not relevant for my problem. The typo referred to below was from an early version of the code that I was trying that I messed up. However fixing it did not solve my problem.

Comment: If the cursor moves in the terminal it means that the pygame window isn't focused, so maybe some bug is happening. I have no problem running it on OSX or Windows 10. Could you might record the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't even work.

Run it in console and you see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 26, in <module>
    for event in pygame.events.get():
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'events'
```

You have typo in

```
for event in pygame.events.get():
```

It has to be `event` without `s` in `pygame.event.get():`

After that code works without problems and I can move object.

It seems you put wrong code in question. Or you run wrong code.

Comment: I must have made the change when trying to get it to work. Regardless your fix does not work for me. I can see the car in the window but hitting the arrow keys does nothing except move the cursor in the console.

Comment: if you see moving cursor in console then you have focus on console, not on PyGame window and then system sends events to console, not to PyGame. Or maybe it is problem only your type of system. I use Linux Mint and I don't have this problem.

Comment: As i mentioned I am certain I have the PyGame window focused and not the console. I have been messing with it for 2 days. I am using Mac OSX. I am following a tutorial video on youtube where the code works just fine but some comments under the video mention a similar problem I am experiencing with no fixes yet.